# Cordova release build blocks ajax requests

Tags: cordova, android-7.1-nougat, nexus-5x

Android Cordova Debug Build works fine on Nexus 5X, 7.1.1 , However it fails to make any ajax requests on Release(Signed) Build.

Tried communicating from native code using a plugin, the connection is successful

The issue occurs only in Nexus 5X, 7.1.1 and doesn't happen on other devices.

**Permissions**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**Whitelist plugin in config.xml:**

```
<feature name="Whitelist">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.whitelist.WhitelistPlugin" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
```

Even tested with logs in ChromeWebViewImpl.java

Returns true when asked for shouldAllow

**CSP:**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src https://mysubdomain.mydomain.com">
```

Please note the CSP works for all Android, iOS devices except for Nexus 5X 7.1.1, i even tried removing connect-src, but same result.

Did anyone come across similar issue ?

Comment: This usually happens when the server have a not trusted certificate

Comment: @jcesarmobile thanks, I did check the server certificate and it looks green and rated A

Comment: Might be not trusted by Android 7.1.1, or might be a bug in Cordova.

Comment: hmm this is just killing me! been trying all options, if Android 7.1.1 doesn't trust how the call made from device works ? and only from web view fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with WebView version 53 and use of Symantec Certificate.

Its a bug in Chrome Version 53

> https://knowledge.symantec.com/support/ssl-certificates-support/index?page=content&id=ALERT2160

Update your Chrome version from playstore you will not face this issue, it has nothing to do with Whitelist plugin.